# How do I undo this connection?

Tags: plumbing, boiler, plumbing-fixture, connectors

How should I undo this connection? It doesn't seem to unscrew, though part of it will move down towards the boiler although this doesnt seem to make it disconnect (I havent tried forcing this though as I don't want it to break)

Its the mains cold water inlet to a small boiler by the way.

Many thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gsSt.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

That little washer looking thing on top at the copper pushes down. Use a wrench the size of the copper tubing to push it down to release its hold on the copper.